# d3 with reactjs for plotting bar graph of population

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-chartjs

I am new to react and I am trying to plot bar graph which will show population race among different countries.

I am trying to achieve something like this.
[population race](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA0NU.gif)

I have looked everywhere but I can't look for any resource through which I can build this. How can I build this in react by consuming external API ?